# SEHException in UWP app - attempting to load DLL for an SDK

Tags: c#, dll, uwp, sdk

I'm trying to use an [SDK](https://www.asus.com/campaign/aura/fl/SDK.html) in a UWP desktop app, but I'm stopped by an exception I don't know quite what means or how to fix it: *InteropServices.SEHException*

I have obtained the source code for a [C# wrapper](https://github.com/nicoco007/AuraSDK) for the SDK, which I have successfully built as a UWP Class library (it was already available on nuget, but I figured maybe I needed to build it for UWP specifically - doesn't seem like the case anymore).

Judging from the debug information, the DLL is loaded and the pointers for delegates are pointing somewhere, but the exception is thrown on this part of the wrapper code:

```
int controllerCount = EnumerateGpuController(IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

This function is defined as:

```
internal int EnumerateGpuController(IntPtr handles, int size) => 
enumerateGpuControllerPointer(handles, size);
```

The pointer is obtained from this:

```
enumerateGpuControllerPointer = (EnumerateGpuControllerPointer)
Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "EnumerateGPU"), typeof(EnumerateGpuControllerPointer));
```

The dllHandle seems valid after confirming that it is loaded.
The DLL is in the project's root and built as content and copied to the Debug directory on build.

Is there a solvable way around this, or is this the sandbox of UWP, making it impossible to use external DLLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically loading and executing code from an external assembly is not supported in a UWP.

All the libraries that you need to load must be in the appx itself.

I will provide you a link to read further more on this topic.

[link to msdn on similar question](http://%20https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf23cd34-ef61-4354-b34b-ff21bd7a4f7c/windows-8-and-assemblyloadfrom?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow up question, but I will post it in another thread.